# Как заполнить матрицу четными/нечетныйми числами в диапазоне от n до m. С#

Tags: c#

Нужен метод который заполняет и выводит матрицу с четными/нечетными числами на экран 
Вот мой метод 
И еще вопрос как заполнить оставшиеся позиции матрицы 0

```
static void CreateEvenNumArray()
        {
            Console.Write("Write Bot : ");
            int Bot = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Write Top : ");
            int Top = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            const int L = 5;
            const int C = 6;
            int[,] arr = new int[L, C];
            int en = Bot;
            for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
                {
                    while (en <= Top)
                    {
                        if (en % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            arr[i, j] = en;
                            Console.Write("{0 , 4}", arr[i, j]);
                        }
                        en++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
static void CreateNumArray()
        {
            const int L = 5;
            const int C = 6;
            int Top, n;
            bool even = false;
            int[,] arr = new int[L, C];

            Console.Write("Write Bot: ");
            int Bot = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            do {
                Console.Write("Write Top: ");
                Top = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Top <= Bot)
                    Console.WriteLine("Top should be more than Bot! Repeat input.");
            } while (Top <= Bot);
            Console.Write("Do you want even array? (Y/N): ");
            String s = Console.ReadLine();
            s = s.ToLower().Trim(' ');
            if (s[0] == 'y')
                even = true;
            if (Bot % 2 == 0) {
                if (even)
                    n = Bot;
                else
                    n = Bot + 1;
            }
            else {
                if (even)
                    n = Bot + 1;
                else
                    n = Bot;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                    if (n <= Top) {
                       arr[i, j] = n;
                       n += 2;
                    }
                    else
                       arr[i, j] = 0;
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", arr[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Метод обобщён на случай чётных и нечётных чисел.

Comment: Маленькое замечание по вашему решению: метод должен выполнять только одну задачу. Нужно отделить работу с консолью в отдельный метод, и создать еще два метода; один отдельный для четных чисел, др. для нечетных. Маленькие методы проще читать/писать, легче отлаживать.

Comment: Читаю вопрос автора: "Нужен метод который заполняет и выводит матрицу с четными/нечетными числами на экран..." Каков вопрос, такой и ответ. Разделить на отдельные методы (что, на мой взгляд, избыточно) усилий не требует. Всё и так предельно просто.